# How to fully validate a X509 certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I need to validate a certificate(X509Certificate2) the same way it´s validated before it is used for communication.

The X509Certificate2.Verify() will in this case return true while the certificate is not issued to the server it is installed on.

Is there any finished code block to do a full validation of the X509 certificate?

Regards

Edit : This is the code I have tried with :

```
var certificate = GetServerCertificate(CertificateStore,CertificateLocation,Thumbprint);

            if(certificate != null)
            {
                if(certificate.Verify())
                    _logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, $"Yes");
                else
                    _logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, $"No");
            }
```

Comment: Please, show what have you tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The X509Certificate2.Verify() will in this case return true while the certificate is not issued to the server it is installed on.

The `Verify` method doesn't check anything about hostnames.  It verifies that

- The certificate is not expired.
- The certificate eventually chains to a trusted root authority.
- All certificates in the chain have appropriately nested expiration.
- The target certificate, unless it's self-issued, has a revocation endpoint, and is not revoked.
- Any intermediate certificates have revocation endpoints and are not revoked.

It's exactly equal to

```
using (X509Chain chain = new X509Chain())
{
    // Use the default vales of chain.ChainPolicy including:
    //  RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online
    //  RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot
    //  VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag
    //  VerificationTime = DateTime.Now
    //  UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)

    bool verified = chain.Build(cert);

    for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainElements.Count; i++)
    {
        chain.ChainElements[i].Certificate.Dispose();
    }

    return verified;
}
```

> Is there any finished code block to do a full validation of the X509 certificate?

If "full validation" just means all the things `Verify` does, then yes.  If you also care that it's valid for use as a TLS client certificate (or TLS server certificate) then you would use the longer form (using X509Chain directly) and add an application policy requirement before calling chain.Build:

```
// See if it's valid as a TLS server
chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add(new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"));
// Alternatively, if it's valid as a TLS client
chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add(new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"));
```

The hostname is much harder.  Client certificates don't have validatable names, it's just up to what the server does with it.  Server certificates have hostname matching against SAN/Subject-CN, but there's nothing built-in that does that check other than just connecting with TLS (`SslStream`).

**Update (2023-09-08)**: Hostnames can be verified on X509Certificate2 instances starting in .NET 7, via the [MatchesHostname](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.matcheshostname?view=net-7.0) method.

Comment: Thanks @bartonjs, så there is no point or way to check that the certificate is issued to the server that is presenting it? Its only possible on the computer that it is installed on? I thought that this was one of the important parts of certificates on internet, to validate that I know who I really talk to?

Comment: @Banshee it’s an important part of TLS/SSL SslStream does the check, but it’s not an easy thing to check outside of SslStream.

Comment: Okay, so to really varify a certificate in .NET I have to try it with a conenction. There is no other reasonable way to make the same extensive check?

Comment: @Banshee If you need to do hostname verification, yes. Remember that a computer can have many different names, and the only thing that matters to TLS is that the certificate matches the name used for that connection.

Comment: @Banshee By the way, .NET 7 added a cert.MatchesHostname routine which I believe you were interested in, which I've just edited into the answer.